# How do I add a script specific lib path in mod_perl?

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl, mod-perl-registry

I'm trying to migrate CGI scripts to `mod_perl` using [`ModPerl::Registry`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html#Registry_Scripts).

The scripts use modules that are in the same directory as the script, but since `mod_perl` current directory is elsewhere, that doesn't work.

I tried using [`FindBin`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) to add on to the `@INC`, but here's what [`FindBin`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) looks like:

```
$FindBin::Bin: /usr/sbin
$FindBin::Script: httpd
```

Which is no use at all.

So, is there a way for the script to figure out where it is, and add that directory to `@INC`? Ideally, all the other scripts using the same Apache server wouldn't get that directory added to their `@INC`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use File::Basename;
use lib dirname( __FILE__ );
```

Comment: I am not sure if `__FILE__` remains unmolested by `mod_perl`. If it is safe, then there is no need for `BEGIN` & `unshift` (besides, there should be no colon after BEGIN.

Comment: This works:
    use File::Basename;
    use lib dirname( __FILE__ );
Your suggestion doesn't work, but it put me on the right track.

Thanks.

Comment: David's suggestion did not work because of the colon after `BEGIN`.

Comment: Be careful, I have had mod_perl empty out %INC on me.  Hartmut Behrens suggestion is how we fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

In your httpd.conf add the following line close to the top:

`PerlRequire /location/of/this/script/startup.pl`

Then in startup.pl, specify the required modules, like so:

`use lib qw(/location/of/module1 /location/of/module1);
1;`

And Presto !

Comment: That makes those directory global. I have many apps running on the same httpd server, I'd rather not mix the include directories.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a separate `Location` or `Directory` for each script or do they all live in the same place? If the former, I would use [`PerlSetEnv`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/config.html#C_PerlSetEnv_)

```
Alias /apps/thisone/ /srv/http/site/apps/thisone/
<Location /apps/thisone/>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
    PerlSetEnv MYLIB /srv/http/site/apps/thisone/lib
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
</Location>
```

If the latter:

```
Alias /apps/ /srv/http/site/apps/
<Location /apps/thisone/>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
    PerlSetEnv THISONE_LIB /srv/http/site/apps/thisone/lib
    PerlSetEnv THATONE_LIB /srv/http/site/apps/thisone/lib
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
</Location>
```

Comment: I assume you then do something like "use lib $ENV{THISONE_LIB}"?

Comment: @Mathieu Yes. In this case David's answer is better though.

Answer (score 1):

Do look at [lib::abs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib::abs). It converts a relative path into an absolute path and is probably ideal for use under mod_perl.